# Command for Multiplying Integers

Tags: macros, latex3

I would like to create a command that can multiply consecutive integers together (if it doesn't already exists).

How do I create a command, say `\multiply{<first_number>}{<last_number>}`, using LaTeX3, that multiplies all the integers from `<first_number>` to `<last_number>`?

Example: I would like `\multiply{4}{9}` to do the multiplication `4*5*6*7*8*9` and return the value `60480`.

Unfortunately, I can't even create some 'starting' code for you (sorry!) since I haven't learned the L3 syntax yet. Therefore, I know it is a 'please do all the work for me' kind of question. `:-(`

Comment: You might like to know that this thing has already been defined and studied and is usually called the [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) with very slightly different notation, in case you want to give it a name which is more specific than `\multiply` or `\Multiply`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The name `\multiply` is already defined (a primitive to multiply a register's value by a number and store the result in that register), hence I use `\product` for the following. Else this is pretty straight forward if you know the relevant L3 functions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \product { m m }
  { \svendtveskaeg_multiply:nn {#1} {#2} }
\cs_new:Npn \svendtveskaeg_multiply:nn #1#2
  {
    \int_eval:n
      { 1 \int_step_function:nnN {#1} {#2} \__svendtveskaeg_multiply:n }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__svendtveskaeg_multiply:n #1 { * #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\product{4}{9}
\typeout{\product{4}{9}}
\end{document}
```

will print 60480 into the document and write it to the log.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\xmultiply#1#2{%
  \ifnum#1=\numexpr#2\relax\the\numexpr#1\relax\else
   \the\numexpr(#2)*\xmultiply{#1}{#2-1}\relax\fi}
\begin{document}

\xmultiply{4}{9} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, David. Your answer is very nice but I've accepted the answer from @Skillmon since I asked for a L3 solution. (Don't get me wrong; I appreciate your answer alot.)

Comment: as long as you don't give the tick to egreg, I don't mind:-) @SvendTveskæg

Comment: Sure thing, David. `:-)` I'll do whatever I can to get you to the very top of the user reputation list. `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

What we can do with OpTeX:

```
\def\multiply#1#2{\expr[0]{#1\fornum #1+1..#2\do{*##1}}}

\multiply{4}{9}

\multiply{4}{15}

\bye
```

Note three features:

- The macro needs only single line of the code.
- We can re-define the TeX primitive `\multiply` without lost of any function of internal macros, because we are doing this in the user name space.
- The `\expr` macro is implemented by Lua expression, the numbers are limited by 2^63 while TeX numbers are limited by 2^31.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. (Note that I've chosen `\Multiply` as the macro name, as there's already a macro called `\multiply`.)

[image]

Observe that the code correctly handles `\Multiply{4}{4}`. If the second argument is smaller than the first, the string "NIL" is returned.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Multiply[2]{\directlua{
  if #2<#1 then tex.sprint ( "NIL" ) 
  else j=#1; for i=#1+1,#2 do j = j*i end; tex.sprint (j)
  end}}
    
\begin{document}
\Multiply{4}{9}, \Multiply{4}{4}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mico. Your answer is very nice but I've accepted the answer from @Skillmon since I asked for a L3 solution. (Don't get me wrong; I appreciate your answer alot.)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the operation you are after is called *Partial Factorial*:

*second number* ! / (*first number*-1) !

Jean-François Burnol's `xintexpr` package can be used for this. It is part of the [`xint`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xint) bundle and it allows for *expandable* arbitrary precision floating point and integer operations.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\begin{document}

\xintiieval{pfactorial(3,9)}% 60480
\typeout{\xintiieval{pfactorial(3,9)}}

\xintiieval{pfactorial(100,130)}% 69293021885203871012298422845822803287591970060789350400000000
\typeout{\xintiieval{pfactorial(100,130)}}

\end{document}
```