# Error: Arithmetic overflow

Tags: latex3, compilation-error

**Motivation**

I'm trying to calculate different probabilities 'automatically', given only some variables such as the number of cards in a sample and the number of cards drawn.

**Code**

The following code consists of a combination of the code from "[Reducing Fractions Automatically Using LaTeX3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253744/15874)" and "[Command for Multiplying Integers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712970/15874)".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \svend_gcd:nn
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#2} = { 0 } {#1}
      { \svend_gcd:ff {#2} { \int_mod:nn {#1} {#2} } }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \svend_gcd:nn { ff }

\int_new:N \l__svend_tmp_int
\cs_new:Nn \svend_reduced:nn
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l__svend_tmp_int { \svend_gcd:nn {#1} {#2} }
    \frac { \svend_reduced_wrap:n { \int_eval:n { #1 / \l__svend_tmp_int } } }
          { \svend_reduced_wrap:n { \int_eval:n { #2 / \l__svend_tmp_int } } }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \svend_reduced_use_wrapper:N
  { \cs_set_eq:NN \svend_reduced_wrap:n #1 }
\svend_reduced_use_wrapper:N \use:n

\msg_new:nnn { svend } { malformed-fraction }
  {
    The~input~you~have~provided~is~malformed.~
    Please~provide~input~in~the~form~of~`p/q'.
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \ReducedFractionWrapper { m }
  { \svend_reduced_use_wrapper:N #1 }

\NewDocumentCommand \ReducedFraction { o > { \SplitList { / } } m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \IfValueT{#1}{\ReducedFractionWrapper{#1}}
    \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:n {#2} = 2 }
      { \svend_reduced:nn #2 }
      { \msg_error:nn { svend } { malformed-fraction } }
    \group_end:
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \produkt { m m }
  { \svend_multiply:nn {#1} {#2} }
\cs_new:Npn \svend_multiply:nn #1#2
  {
    \int_eval:n
      { 1 \int_step_function:nnN {#1} {#2} \__svend_multiply:n }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__svend_multiply:n #1 { * #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\def\roed{5}
\def\sort{9}
\newcommand*\kortTotal{\fpeval{\roed+\sort}}
\def\udtraek{10}

\begin{equation}
  \ReducedFraction[\num]
    {(\produkt{\kortTotal-\udtraek+1}{\kortTotal}-\produkt{1}{\udtraek})
     /\produkt{\kortTotal-\udtraek+1}{\kortTotal}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Error**

I get the error

```
! Arithmetic overflow.
<recently read> \__int_eval_end: 
                 
l.66 ...\produkt{\kortTotal-\udtraek+1}{\kortTotal}}
```

When I change `\def\udtraek{10}` to `\def\udtraek{9}`, it compiles just fine. The number is obviously too big (which is also indicated by `Arithmetic overflow`) but I don't know how to adjust the code so that I can use larger numbers.

**Question**

How do I change the code so that I can use larger input integers?

Comment: Perlhaps a good thing to do is explain what exactly it is you are trying to do in the first place. Isn't quite clear for me by reading the code.

Comment: Well your issue here is that your products are just too big for TeX's `count` register size/expression. You could use `bigintcalc` for the work (we have some unreleased `expl3` that does some but not all of the same). But as mentioned already, perhaps the question could do with some motivation.

Comment: As mentioned in one of the linked questions, `xintexpr` could also be used to implement the arbitrary precision required

Comment: @daleif Please see top of updated post.

Comment: @JosephWright Please see top of updated post. Thanks - I'll see if I can make it work using `xintexpr`. If you have an elegant implementation, I'd be happy to see your solution.

Comment: I haven't followed the code but if you are calculating probablilities do you need integer arithmetic, or can you use floating point?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do need integer arithmetic, unfortunately; I also have to calculate both the numerator and the denominator explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, your best option here is likely [`xint`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xint)'s `\xintiieval`, which can work with large integers *and* parse expressions. (There is some non-released [`expl3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/expl3) code in this area, but it needs a few bits of finishing; [`bigintcalc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bigintcalc) doesn't do expressions.)

Taking that route and simplifying to highlight just the key points:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\svend@saved@gcd{}
\NewDocumentCommand\ReducedFraction{O{\@firstofone}mm}
  {%
    \edef\svend@saved@gcd{gcd(#2,#3)}%
    \expanded{%
      \noexpand\frac
        {%
          \noexpand#1%
            {\xintiieval{#2/\svend@saved@gcd}}%
        }%
        {%
          \noexpand#1%
            {\xintiieval{#3/\svend@saved@gcd}}%
        }%
     }% 
  }
\makeatother
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\produkt{mm}
  {\xintiieval{pfactorial(#1,#2)}}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\def\roed{5}
\def\sort{9}
\newcommand*\kortTotal{}
\edef\kortTotal{\xintiieval{\roed+\sort}}
\def\udtraek{9}

\begin{equation}
  \ReducedFraction[\num]
    {(\produkt{\kortTotal-\udtraek+1}{\kortTotal}-\produkt{1}{\udtraek})}
    {\produkt{\kortTotal-\udtraek+1}{\kortTotal}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the fraction not being reduced: example?

Comment: Everything is fine. Sorry. Unrelated: Are there any plans for when the relevant `expl` code for my question will be released?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Well it wasn't on the agenda at all, but I am wonder if we should tidy up and get it out. Mainly a question of implementing division - I'll make a start on that